# How can I include Metafield data into the Shopify product.description property?

Tags: shopify, product, liquid

I am working with a shopify 2.0 theme and I would like to include relevant product datapoints (meta fields) in the product.description property.

Examples—

- Condition: New
- Brand: Hester & Orchard
- Department: Womens
- Size: M
- Size Type: Regular
- Color: Blue
- Pattern: Solid
- Closure: Pullover
- Sleeve Length: Short Sleeve
- Chest Size: 42 in
- Length: 23 in
- Material: Cotton Blend
- Country: China

I need these rendered specifically in the description property so that each key:value are available and readable for outside listings.

I am currently producing this list on my store product page using a snippet right under the description, but my ultimate goal is to make these meta fields the product.description content inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

So just save all that data in the description? Why waste effort on saving them as metafields, when you say you want them as a description.